# Can't install iso3166 module on conda evnironment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, iso

I need ability to parse ISO3 code into ISO3166 in Python.

Because of that I want to add [iso3166](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso3166) Python module to my Conda environment. I always receive this error:

> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '

And this is what I tried (according to [link1](https://anaconda.org/mcrot/iso3166) or [link2](https://anaconda.org/auto/iso3166)):

```
(my_env) Kamils-MacBook-Pro:~ F1sherKK$ conda install -c mcrot iso3166=0.7
Fetching package metadata ...........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '


(my_env) Kamils-MacBook-Pro:~ F1sherKK$ conda install -c mcrot iso3166=0.8
Fetching package metadata ...........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '


(my_env) Kamils-MacBook-Pro:~ F1sherKK$ conda install -c auto iso3166=0.8
Fetching package metadata ...........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '


(my_env) Kamils-MacBook-Pro:~ F1sherKK$ conda install -c auto iso3166=0.5
Fetching package metadata ...........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '


(my_env) Kamils-MacBook-Pro:~ F1sherKK$ conda install iso3166
Fetching package metadata .........
```

How can I install it so I can share it with other team members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the contents of the webpage at https://anaconda.org/mcrot/iso3166 , you will notice that the conda package is only available for platforms: Linux(64bit) and Windows(64bit) and is not available for OSX(32/64bit), hence conda keeps telling you that the package is not found.

[image]

As to the issue of conda not stating exactly what was not found, the bug was reported at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4860, fixed and released in [v4.3.16](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.3.16)